# How to read variables from POST payload in gin gonic?

Tags: go, go-gin

On Chrome's Network tab the request payload looks like the following:

```
{"req":{"headers":{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer **************"}}},"name":"john"}
```

I removed the bearer authorization.

```
func name(c *gin.Context) {    
    name := c.Param("name")
    fmt.Println("name", name)
}
```

I'm most definitly doing something wrong but I've searched and couldn't find the solution.
How do I retrieve something from there? If I use the rawData function I can see that the server got the response but I don't know how to actually put it in a variable that I can use

Comment: I assume GetHeader reads an HTTP header and not the body, and the payload looks like the http request's json body. HTTP headers and HTTP body are not one and the same part of an HTTP request. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message)

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I mean @mkopriva. I updated the code with only what is not working

Comment: Right you are, I misunderstood. However, you're still using the wrong method to read the HTTP body. [Param](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Param) is for reading path parameters.

Comment: So which one is it? I've tried basically all of them to see if any worked but none did

Comment: Given the payload's syntax I assume you're sending json in the request's body, to read that use binding https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation

Comment: So there's no way to just read the string without binding it to a structure? I don't want to create a new structure just for this, it seems unnecessary

Comment: You can always get the [http.Request](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Request) and read its body however you like.

Comment: You can read request body and unmarshall it as map[string]interface{}. Then get values from it. But it requires type casts and gets ugly quite quickly with nested data. So, if you only need name parameter, it might be ok. But if you also  need the Authorization header, then binding will be simpler and cleaner. See raw string parsing example here: https://play.golang.org/p/KwIJ01d_Nlb

Answer (score 0):

```
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
fmt.Printf("ctx.Request.body: %v", string(data))
```